# C++: how to use a template on both classes and primitives?

Tags: c++, templates, reference

I have a question about templates that can be used with parameters that are either a class or a primitive type. Here's some sample code:

(Note: I have real code that's more complex, the following code is useless but it reproduces the same issue)

```
template<typename T>
class Foo
{
  T value;

public:
  Foo() {}
  const T& getValue() const { return value; }
  Foo& setValue(const T& other) { 
    value = other; return *this; 
  }
};

struct Bar
{
  int x;

  Bar() : x(3) {}
};

int doit()
{
  Foo<int> fooint;
  Bar bar;
  bar.x = 44;
  Foo<Bar> foobar;

  fooint.setValue(3);      // warning here
  foobar.setValue(bar);

  int y = foobar.getValue().x + fooint.getValue();
  return y;
}
```

I get a compiler remark on `fooint.setValue()`:

```
value copied to temporary, reference to temporary used
```

I understand the remark. What I'm wondering is how I should handle `Foo::setValue()` if I'm going to use Foo with both primitives and class/struct types as template parameters.

I thought `setValue(const T& other)` was the right method signature for passing in a constant class by reference.

Is there a way to make setValue() so it "does the right thing" both for `Foo<int>` and `Foo<Bar>`?

Comment: That is perfectly fine. I don't think that is harmful in any way.

Comment: It's a TI compiler for their 28xx DSPs. On a regular PC I wouldn't care about this, but in an embedded system, it has me slightly concerned.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is perfectly legal to bind temporaries to const references as you do in `setValue()`. Intel C++, which issues this remark, is not being helpful in this case.

EDIT: I am guessing that TI compiler is based on Intel, which, for me, issues the following diagnostic on that line:

```
test.cc(28): remark #383: value copied to temporary, reference to temporary used
    fooint.setValue(3);      // warning here
```

The diagnostic is discussed on http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/cdiag383/  where it says

> Can safely ignore this warning for pushback function of vector. The vector copies the argument into its own storage; it never stores the original argument. Therefore, using a temporary is perfectly safe.

In your case, you're also copying the argument, therefore it can also be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

I see nothing wrong with your code. GCC compiles it without errors or warnings.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your last question of getting `Foo<T>::setValue()` to do the 'right thing' you can consider using template specialization to accomplish that -- a fairly common technique used in template metaprogramming. Something like this for example:

```
template <typename T>
struct Ref_or_Value
{
    typedef T& type;
};

template <typename T>
struct Ref_or_Value<T *>
{
    typedef T* type;
};

template <>
struct Ref_or_Value<int>
{
    typedef int type;
};

// add other primitive types like above as need
```

The `Foo<T>::setValue` signature then becomes:

```
Foo& setValue(const typename Ref_or_Value<T>::type other);
```

Whether this is overkill or not I'll let you decide but this should get setValue to do the 'right thing'. If `T=int` then setValue will take arguments by value. If `T=Foobar_object` then it will be by const reference.

Comment: What's wrong with taking an int by reference? Template classes do this sort of thing all the time (e.g. `vector::push_back(T&)`).

Comment: @HighCommander4, `vector::push_back` takes its parameter by *const* reference. If it took it by non-const reference, you wouldn't be able to append a literal `int` value at all. What Jason's compiler is warning about, apparently, is that it has to generate a temporary for that literal so that it can create a reference for it. And *that's* what's wrong with passing an `int` by reference. For compilers that can't optimize that away, you'd want to make sure parameters get passed the best possible way, whatever their type. Victor's `Ref_or_Value` template does that.

Comment: Sorry, I did of course mean `vector::push_back(const T&)`. My point was, if this were a problem surely `vector` would have come with specializations for built-in types to maximize efficiency?

Comment: @HighCommander4 that compiler needlessly warns about `vector::push_back` too, see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't produce any warning/error/whatsoever for me on Visual Studio 2010. It is very weird that your compiler shows that diagnostic, as it's non-sense. `3` is an rvalue, and rvalues are explicitly allowed to bind to constant references like `const int&`.